# Apt in ubuntu: Failed to fetch url: 404 Not Found

Tags: ubuntu, packages, aptitude

Trying to install gvim:

```
soid@ubuntu:~$ sudo aptitude install vim-gnome
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information
Initializing package states... Done
Writing extended state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gvfs{a} gvfs-backends{a} indicator-application{a} libappindicator0{a} libbonoboui2-0{a} libdbusmenu-gtk1{a} libgail18{a} libglade2-0{a} libgnome2-0{a}
  libgnomecanvas2-0{a} libgnomeui-0{a} libgtk2.0-0{a} libgtk2.0-bin{a} libgtk2.0-common{a} libindicator0{a} libsoup-gnome2.4-1{a} libsoup2.4-1{a}
  policykit-1-gnome{a} vim-gnome
0 packages upgraded, 19 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,083kB/6,907kB of archives. After unpacking 41.5MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] Y
Writing extended state information... Done
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main libgtk2.0-common 2.20.1-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.30 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main libgtk2.0-0 2.20.1-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.30 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main libsoup2.4-1 2.30.1-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.30 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main libsoup-gnome2.4-1 2.30.1-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.30 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main libgail18 2.20.1-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.30 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main libgtk2.0-bin 2.20.1-0ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.30 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtk+2.0/libgtk2.0-common_2.20.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb: 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.30 80]
```

I've checked ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtk+2.0/libgtk2.0-common_2.20.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb on other mirrors but it doesn't exist anywhere.
How could I pass over that?

Answer (score 4):

`aptitude` caches the version IDs of available packages every time you run `aptitude update`.  If Ubuntu (or Debian) issues a new version of a given package, then the old version will no longer be available.  Attempting to install it will cause the errors you're seeing.  Re-running `sudo aptitude update` before your install will clear up the problem.  You may also want to run `sudo aptitude autoclean` to get rid of outdated package files that may have been downloaded, but will no longer be needed (having been superseded by newer versions).

Comment: thank you, after sudo apt-get install aptitude and sudo aptitude update I could run my updates again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try aptitude update